# Tests failing when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7 - "CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

After upgrading to Boot 2.7 the integration tests that were using an embedded H2 database started failing.

I see this WARN message in the logs, but it's not very clear the cause or the solution for this:

```
WARN 8053 ---[           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     :GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table user (id bigint generated by default as identity, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id bigint generated by default as identity, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table [*]user (id bigint generated by default as identity, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table user (id bigint generated by default as identity, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) [42001-212]
...
```

It seems my `User` table is not created after the upgrade, thus making my tests fail.

Answer (score 6):

It seems Boot 2.7 upgraded to its H2 dependency to 2.x, which is not backward compatible and introduces several changes:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#h2-21

The issue was that `User` is now a Keyword / reserved word (The [H2 "migration-to-v2" guide](http://www.h2database.com/html/migration-to-v2.html) was not very helpful in my case; it mentioned new keywords were added, but it didn't provide a link to ):

https://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords

So, what I had to do is use ["quoted names"](https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#quoted_name) to define the Table name of my Entity (it seems I can use backticks in the table annotation too instead of escaping double quotes):

```
@Table(name="\"user\"")
@Entity
public class User {
...
```

I also had to use double quotes on my `data.sql` files for this table:

```
INSERT INTO "user"(id, email, name) VALUES(1, 'test@user.com', 'Test User');
```

Note: the migration guide also mentions the possibility of using [the `SET NON_KEYWORDS` command](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_non_keywords) as a workaround, but it also discourages it.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `src/test/resources/application-test.properties` file (assuming your tests run with the `test` profile):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true
```

If any of your JPA entities have `UUID` fields, ensure those fields are annotated with `@Column` and the annotation's `columnDefinition` defines the column as type `UDID`. (In its simplest form: `@Column(columnDefinition="UDID")`.) This works around a [Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15373).

Comment: Thank you, just adding `@Column(columnDefinition="UDID")` to relevant columns stopped my tests from failing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of Identity columns in schema.sql.Identity columns should be normally declared with GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY.
Ex: JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT IDENTITY --  should be changed as JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY.

Refer http://www.h2database.com/html/migration-to-v2.html for more such changes occurred due to upgrade in H2 version.